# What is N件事? (Cantonese)

Tags: cantonese, slang

I saw the title of a video: 關於福麵嘅N件事.
福麵 is a brand of noodles with a huge 福 writing on the packaging. What then is N件事? Is it a Cantonese slang I am unaware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It means 'numerous/several facts about Fuku Noodle'.
2. The slang `N` has an algebraic etymology which denotes an *unspecified but large* number (e.g., 1, 2, 3, ..., N). Apparently this emerged in the early eighties (see more [here](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/14179/when-did-the-usage-of-n-to-indicate-some-unspecified-quantity-come-up)).

   `件` is the counter for `事` ('a thing; a matter', here its meaning is fairly abstract and dummy-like, meaning whatever that is about Fuku noodle). In fact it is common to add
   counters after `N`: `N樣嘢` ('many things'), `N次` ('many times'),
   `N年前` ('many years ago') etc.

   Of course, we don't expect countlessly many facts in a short video. Using `N` is often exaggeration.

Answer (score 1):

'n' is a common symbol for 'unknow number' in the maths textbook,

N年前 = so many years ago/ unknown number of years ago

N樣嘢 = so many things/ unknown number of things

I did wonder why use 'n' but not X or Y for unknown numbers? Then I thought, oh, the word 'number' starts with an 'n'

I also wondered since 'n' can be a small number, why we use it for numerous, Then I thought, small number is easy to remember, If there are only a few things about 福麵, we would just state the exact number. We say 'N件事' because there are too many things that the exact number became unknown

Example:

我妹妹有兩個男朋友，我點知你講邊個? - My sister has two boyfriends, how do I know which one you are talking about?

我妹妹有咁多個男朋友，我點知你講邊個? - My sister has so many boyfriends, how do I know which one you are talking about?

我妹妹有N個男朋友，我點知你講邊個? - My sister has numerous boyfriends, how do I know which one you are talking about? (I stopped counting after the fifth)